# Multiple OR in SQL to find all the possible entries for a common characteristic

Tags: mysql, sql

Folks,
This is my SQL code

```
   SELECT LayerA From ATable WHERE Label  LIKE '%NS%' OR '%NI%‘ OR ‘%NES%’ OR ‘%NEI%’;
```

I need to see all the entries that i might contain any of those string labels. The query is not working. Any idea idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The way you used `LIKE` and `OR` is not correct. It should be this way:

```
SELECT LayerA 
FROM   ATable 
WHERE  Label LIKE '%NS%'  
       OR Label LIKE '%NI%'  
       OR Label LIKE '%NES%'  
       OR Label LIKE '%NEI%'
```

Another thing is to use single quote `'` not `‘`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT LayerA From ATable WHERE Label  LIKE '%NS%' OR Label  LIKE '%NI%' OR '%NES%' Label  LIKE OR '%NEI%';
```

You were using ‘ instead of '!!

Comment: yes, yes. i didn't saw that .. you are right! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input